# How to check a column in a row if it has a same value?

Tags: php, mysql

I'd like to check a column in a table if they have the same value.

```
ID    School_Name     Student    Status
1        Virginia        Alex         2
2        Virginia        John         2
3       Wonderbow        Devi         1
4     San Antonio       Lucas         1
5     San Antonio       Larsa         2
```

How to check the column `status` if the value is `2` for each `School_Name`. The output is some thing like this:

```
ID       School_Name    school_stat
 1          Virginia      TRUE      
 2         Wonderbow     FALSE
 3       San Antonio     FALSE
```

So, if all student in each school name has the status of 2, the result is TRUE.

Current Query:

`SELECT *,SUM(case when status > 1 then TRUE else FALSE end) as school_stat from t_school`

The query giving wrong output though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    School_Name,
    IF(COUNT(1) = COUNT(IF(Status = 2, 1, NULL)), 'TRUE', 'FALSE') school_stat
FROM t_school
GROUP BY School_Name
```

See [**demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ab03d4/1) in SQLFiddle, and if you want to do some aggregation things, non-aggregation column like `id` will make no sense in select.

Comment: Thank you so much. by the way, what is `COUNT(1)` ?

Comment: @ashura91 same result with `count(*)`. Also you can google it.

Answer (score 0):

> Use `group by` clause for group your **school_name**.

Example,

```
SELECT ID,School_Name,(case when status > 1 then 'TRUE' else 'FALSE' end) as school_stat from temp1
group by School_Name
order by ID asc;
```

See [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4395b9/1).